# Why is Paris flooded in Edge Of Tomorrow?

Tags: edge-of-tomorrow

In the climactic act of Edge Of Tomorrow we see the ruins of Paris, extending as far as the Louvre.

The entire area surrounding this site seems to be flooded in a foot of water or more.

How and why did this flooding happen?

Comment: http://joshspector.com/how-to-flood-paris-in-a-movie/

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I spoke with the film's writer; Chris McQuarrie and he [confirmed](https://twitter.com/Answerguesser40/status/609100007791300608) that the Seine had been blocked when the Eiffel Tower collapsed across it, which had in turn caused the city to flood.

> **Q.** *Quick question. In "Edge of Tomorrow", why was Paris flooded?*
>
> **A.** *The Eiffel Tower had collapsed across the Seine, creating a damn* [sic]. *It's glimpsed (too?) briefly in the establishing shot.*

[image]
**Apologies for quality. I've had to use software to enhance the contrast to make this shot visible**

Comment: Which seems a little incomplete, as the Eiffel Tower is mostly empty space, anyway.  I assume the concrete embankment around the area must have also collapsed, and that there was ample time for detritus to get stuck on the tower and clog up it's ample openings.  I suppose that must be what he meant by it "creating a damn". Cool way to get an answer.  +1

Comment: I was going to point that out too. There's no way the Eiffel Tower on its own would block the whole river.

Comment: Is there anything you don't know?

Comment: @KyloRen - There's a world of information out there if you just ask. Many writers are more than happy to share if you find them on twitter, facebook or email. I emailed Alan Dean Foster about a word in the "Aliens" novelisation a few days back. I got a reply in under 5 minutes.

Comment: Thats it, how do you know Alan Dean Foster's email?

Comment: @KyloRen - It's on his website.

Answer (score 35):

In reality, the Louvre is on the Right Bank of the Seine river.  The Seine has a [history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seine#Flooding) of flooding that goes back centuries.  I don't think there is much of an explanation besides, 'The Seine flooded again'.

Comment: http://lishi.huisongshu.com/img/uploak/1/1788.jpg

Comment: One assumes that the battle has destroyed the bridges and clogged the Seine. Simple really.

Comment: I like the simplicity.  Sometimes, a cigar is just a cigar.